# Printing table elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript array that contains a `string` which is in the format `<td>200</td><td>I3</td><td>NAME NAME</td><td>EXTRA</td>`

Example Array[0] contains `<td>200</td><td>I3</td><td>NAME NAME</td><td>EXTRA</td>`
 which is a string (and so on)

How do I print a html table while iterating through the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this:

```
var html = '<table><tr>' + myarray.join('</tr><tr>') + '</tr></table>';
```

For example:

```js
myarray = [
    '<td>200</td><td>I3</td><td>NAME NAME</td><td>EXTRA</td>',
    '<td>150</td><td>I1</td><td>Some data</td><td>-999</td>',
    '<td>360</td><td>K9</td><td>other data</td><td>nothing</td>',
];

var html = '<table border=1><tr>' + myarray.join('</tr><tr>') + '</tr></table>';

document.querySelector('#mytablemustcomehere').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="mytablemustcomehere"></div>
```

Comment: and I can use document.write(html) to print the entire table?

Comment: Yes, I added that just now.

Comment: Except `document.write` is a big code smell. Better to use `innerHTML`.

Comment: Indeed, this is just for demo. Be careful with `document.write`. It is better to locate where you want to insert it, and then assign to `innerHTML`. I have updated my snippet to do just that.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through your array elements and add `<tr>` to them for each row.

```js
var arr = ["<td>200</td><td>I3</td><td>NAME NAME 1</td><td>EXTRA 1</td>", 
           "<td>100</td><td>I2</td><td>NAME NAME 2</td><td>EXTRA 2</td>"];

var str = "";

var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) str += "<tr>"+arr[i]+"</tr>";

table.innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

Answer (score 2):

@trincot's answer is best for the specific question. I'd like to expand a little on how to do this using the DOM API instead.

```
function createRowHTML(itemData) {
  return '<tr><td>' + itemData.join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>';
}

function appendTableTo(element, items) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  table.innerHTML = items.map(createRowHTML).join('');
  element.appendChild(table);
}

var items = [
  [200, 'I3', 'NAME NAME 1', 'EXTRA 1'], 
  [100, 'I2', 'NAME NAME 2', 'EXTRA 2']
];

appendTableTo(document.querySelector('body'), items);
```